# Assertion in Mocha callback not working

Tags: javascript, node.js, mocha.js

I have the following mocha test.  I'm trying to put in an assertion and test a failure.  Whenever there is a failure in the assertion in a callback, mocha still thinks the test passed. I've tried both the assert and expect modules.

```
var sendSecureQueue = SecureQueue(secureBullOptions.encryption, "Server A");
var receiveSecureQueue = SecureQueue(secureBullOptions.encryption, "Server A");

describe('SecureQueue', function () {
    describe('and() and process() - unencrypted', function () {
        it('should be equal to each other, for both Queue and SecureQueue', function () {
            var sendSecureData = {msg: "Hello"};
            console.log("Send Secure Data: " + util.inspect(sendSecureData));
            sendSecureQueue.add(sendSecureData);

            receiveSecureQueue.process(function (job, done) {
                var receivedSecureData = job.data;
                console.log("Received secure data", util.inspect(receivedSecureData));

                //**Testing Force a Failure**
                //assert.equal(1,2);
                //**Testing Force a Failure**
                expect(1).to.be.equal(2);

                done();
            });
        });

    });
});
```

Mocha output - with assertion/expect:

```
  SecureQueue
    and() and process() - unencrypted
Send Secure Data: { msg: 'Hello' }
      ✓ should be equal to each other, for both Queue and SecureQueue                                             

Received secure data { msg: 'Hello' }
(node:16349) Warning: a promise was created in a handler at /usr/apps/myapp/node_modules/bull/lib/queue.js:688:9 but was not returned from it, see ...
    at new Promise (/usr/apps/myapp/node_modules/bluebird/js/release/promise.js:77:14)

  1 passing (120ms)

(node:16349) Warning: .then() only accepts functions but was passed: [object Object]
```

Mocha output - Commenting out assertion/expect:

```
  SecureQueue
    and() and process() - unencrypted
Send Secure Data: { msg: 'Hello' }
      ✓ should be equal to each other, for both Queue and SecureQueue                                             


  1 passing (102ms)

Received secure data { msg: 'Hello' }
```

Comment: The done callback should be passed through as a parameter into the callback of the `it` suite e.g. `it('should be equal to each other, for both Queue and SecureQueue', function (done) {`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since you're testing asynchronous behavior (in this case a callback rather than a promise), you need to add a callback to `it()` (usually called `done`) to tell mocha that your test has completed:

```
it('should be equal to each other, for both Queue and SecureQueue', function (done) {
  var sendSecureData = {msg: "Hello"};
  console.log("Send Secure Data: " + util.inspect(sendSecureData));
  sendSecureQueue.add(sendSecureData);

  receiveSecureQueue.process(function (job) {
    var receivedSecureData = job.data;
    console.log("Received secure data", util.inspect(receivedSecureData));

    expect(1).to.equal(2);
    done();
  });
});
```

The syntax for `expect` should not have both `be` and `equal`, testing for equality can be written in either of these 2 forms using `expect.js`:

```
expect(1).to.equal(2);
expect(1).to.be(2);
```